# If a function has a jacobian with linearly independent columns on a set B, is the following union equal to B?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure, jacobian

Suppose we have a function $f : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with the condition that the rows of the Jacobian matrix of $f$ are linearly independent on $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$.

Let $B_p$ = $\{ t \in B : \forall s \in \mathbb{R}^m  \; \; \lvert s - t \rvert < \frac{1}{p} \implies \frac{\lvert s - t \rvert}{p} \leq \lvert f(s) - f(t) \rvert \}$

I believe it's the case that $\lambda(\bigcup\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} B_{p}) = 0 \implies \lambda(B) = 0$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^m$, but I've been unable to prove it.

---

Noting that the precondition necessitates that $ n \leq m$, the case where $m = 1$ is pretty simple, as the precondition reduces to $f$ having non-zero derivative on $B$.

I'm not entirely sure how to proceed. An argument by induction on $m$ is tempting, but I'm struggling to see exactly how to utilise the linear independence of the rows in this proof.

Comment: Is f continuously differentiable?

Comment: No, not necessarily. (Unless this is somehow implied by the condition on the Jacobian on $B$?)

Comment: If $f: \Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ is the projection to the first component you only have one row in the jacobian that is never $0$ hence the condition is always satisfied. However $B_p=\emptyset$ always. Did you mean the columns to be linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto x$. The Jacobian of this map is at every point simply $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}$, which is one non-zero column hence the columns are all linearly independent.

However for any $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ and $p\in\Bbb R_{>0}$ you have that $\|(x,y)-(x,y+\frac1{2p})\|<\frac1p$ but
$$\|f(x,y)-f(x,y+\frac1{2p})\|=0\not≥ \frac{\|(x,y)-(x,y+\frac1{2p})\|}{p}$$
hence for any set $B$ the set $B_p$ is empty.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed this. The question is stated as I intended. Perhaps it's the case that if we say "for almost all $s$" rather than "for all $s$" then the statement holds.

Comment: The set of points $s$ for which the inequality
$$\frac{|s-t|}p≤|f(s)-f(t)|$$
holds is closed. So the set of points where it fails is open, if it is not empty it cannot be of zero measure.

Comment: This example is the prototype of the case where the differential is not injective. You can adapt it to see that $B_p$ does not contain any points where the differential has a kernel. On the other hand one can also see that $\bigcup_p B_p$ contains every point where the differential is injective (ie where the columns are linearly independent). It follows that $\bigcup_p B_p$ is exactly all those points of $B$ where the differential is injective.